# Font Awesome icon does not apply parent CSS rules

Tags: css, font-awesome

The video-preview-cover has to remain, just invisible. I can't manage to make the font awesome icon hide with the rest of the content. I've tried any tricks I know of

http://codepen.io/QwisoDev/pen/jEbgzo

```
.video-preview-cover:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

This CSS hides all of the text and 'uncovers' the placeholder below but it doesn't apply to the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix to your problem

```
.video-preview-cover:hover .fa-heart {
 display: none!important; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I don't know CSS selectors well at all, if that wasn't obvious. :] Thank you

Comment: There is a timer to accept on new submissions. Done and done. Cheers